# How to open URI defined in Websocket (written as java maven project) in chrome?

Tags: java

[Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) is a full WebSocket server and client implementation in Java SE, no enterprise/web app server needed. I tried to use this code to make a simple java client and server.

I am able to run the code and see output in the console, but when I open the given url in Chrome (http://127.0.0.2:8080), I am getting:

> Websocket upgrade failure error 404

Can someone help me with this?

#### Client

```java
public class ExampleClient extends WebSocketClient {
    public ExampleClient( URI serverUri , Draft draft ) {
        super( serverUri, draft );
    }

    public ExampleClient( URI serverURI ) {
        super( serverURI );
    }

    public ExampleClient( URI serverUri, Map<String, String> httpHeaders ) {
        super(serverUri, httpHeaders);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshakedata ) {
        send("Hello, it is me. Mario :)");
        System.out.println( "opened connection" );
        // if you plan to refuse connection based on ip or httpfields overload: onWebsocketHandshakeReceivedAsClient
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage( String message ) {
        System.out.println( "received: " + message );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
        // The codecodes are documented in class org.java_websocket.framing.CloseFrame
        System.out.println( "Connection closed by " + ( remote ? "remote peer" : "us" ) + " Code: " + code + " Reason: " + reason );
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // if the error is fatal then onClose will be called additionally
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws URISyntaxException {
        ExampleClient c = new ExampleClient( new URI( "ws://localhost:8887" )); // more about drafts here: http://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/wiki/Drafts
        c.connect();
    }
}
```

#### Server

```java
public class ChatServer extends WebSocketServer {
    public ChatServer( int port ) throws UnknownHostException {
        super( new InetSocketAddress( port ) );
    }

    public ChatServer( InetSocketAddress address ) {
        super( address );
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen( WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake ) {
        conn.send("Welcome to the server!"); //This method sends a message to the new client
        broadcast( "new connection: " + handshake.getResourceDescriptor() ); //This method sends a message to all clients connected
        System.out.println( conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress() + " entered the room!" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose( WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
        broadcast( conn + " has left the room!" );
        System.out.println( conn + " has left the room!" );
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage( WebSocket conn, String message ) {
        broadcast( message );
        System.out.println( conn + ": " + message );
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage( WebSocket conn, ByteBuffer message ) {
        broadcast( message.array() );
        System.out.println( conn + ": " + message );
    }


    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException , IOException {
        int port = 8887; // 843 flash policy port
        try {
            port = Integer.parseInt( args[ 0 ] );
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        }

        ChatServer s = new ChatServer( port );
        s.start();
        System.out.println( "ChatServer started on port: " + s.getPort() );

        BufferedReader sysin = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
        while ( true ) {
            String in = sysin.readLine();
            s.broadcast( in );
            if( in.equals( "exit" ) ) {
                s.stop(1000);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError( WebSocket conn, Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if( conn != null ) {
            // some errors like port binding failed may not be assignable to a specific websocket
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Server started!");
        setConnectionLostTimeout(0);
        setConnectionLostTimeout(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I Googled for "Websocket upgrade failure" and there are several answers. I suggest you look at them. Some of them may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

The web browser address field performs an HTTP GET request to the given URL, which is somewhat different than a WebSocket handshake. That's why you got the given error message. You can't connect to a WebSocket server using your browser as a client just like that.